# C++ Template w/ Pointers - Could not convert template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a template

```
template <class object_t, long size, object_t nullObject>
class lf_deque
{
  // ...
}
```

when I try to instantiate this template with an int, it compiles fine, but if I try to instantiate with a pointer i get the error:

```
could not convert template argument '0' to 'int*'
```

```
lf_deque<int,  10, 0> intDeque; // WORKS
lf_deque<int*, 10, 0> ptrDeque; // ERROR
```

any thoughts or ideas why i would get this inconsistency?

Comment: What is the compiler? This compiles fine on MSVC 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In templates when a function/class is resolved with <strike>ADL(Argument Dependent Lookup)</strike> *Function Template Argument Deduction*, there is no implicit conversion. Only exactly matching paramters can resolve to instantiate a appropriate template function/class. That is the root cause of the error.

The compiler tells you that it cannot implicitly convert last parameter `0` to `int *`, Since when you pass first argument as `int *`, `object_t` is `int *` and the compiler expects an `int *` as the third argument as well. It tells you that `0` is an invalid type as the third argument for the class template.

Comment: However there's no implicit conversion converting 0 to a pointer anyway. Instead, 0 (or actually, any constant integral expression of integer type with value zero) is a special case (a null pointer literal). I believe it should work in this example and suspect a compiler bug. Anyway, the workaround is easy: Just add an explicit cast.

Comment: There is no argument dependent lookup happening here. Argument dependent lookup is for finding overload resolution candidate functions in namespace associated with argument types, but there are neither functions, overloads nor namespaces involved here.

Comment: I suppose you meant parameter type deduction, but that again only applies to functions and there are no functions involved here.

Comment: I believe this answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what the standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E)) has to say, in "14.3.21 Template non-type arguments [temp.arg.nontype] [#5], page 331:

> Although 0 is a valid template-argument for a non-type template-parameter of
>   integral type, it is not
>   a valid template-argument for a non-type template-parameter of pointer type. However, both `(int*)0`
>   and `nullptr` are valid template-arguments for a non-type template-parameter of type “pointer to int.”

In particular, argument dependent lookup has nothing to do in this case, the reason of the error is that the only allowed conversions for a pointer nontype  template argument are: qualification conversions, array-to-pointer conversion
 or, if the template argument is of type `std::nullptr_t` - null pointer conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Do  you really need to pass nullObject instance as part of the template?  Could you do it through a constructor instead?

The following compiles using g++

```
#include <string>


template <class object_t, long size>
class lf_deque
{
public:
    lf_deque(const object_t& nullObject){
        //...
    };

protected:
    lf_deque(){
        // ... 
    };  
};

int main(){

    lf_deque<int,10> intDeque(0);
    lf_deque<std::string,10> myStringDeque("");

    int myInt = 4;
    lf_deque<int*,10> intPtrDeque(&myInt);

    lf_deque<int*,10> intPtrDequeZero(0);

    return 0;
}
```

If this isn't workable maybe you could store the value as a static member instead.

```
#include <string>

template <class object_t, long size>
class lf_deque 
{
public:
    lf_deque(){
        //..
    }
    static object_t nullObject;
};
template<class object_t, long size> object_t lf_deque<object_t,size>::nullObject;

int main(){

    lf_deque<int,10>::nullObject = 0;
    lf_deque<int,10> intDeque;

    lf_deque<int*,10>::nullObject = 0;
    lf_deque<int*,10> intPtrDeque;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, because the code samples are good, but the point about ADL is wrong. No *argument dependent lookup* ever happens here.

Comment: The first example ended up being the solution i chose. I didn't need the nullObject to be defined as a template parameter. I passed it in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks to @Jan for the comments about ADL being incorrect.  I've edited the answer accordingly.